# Postgres missing FROM-clause entry for table error caused by WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT books.id, author, title, price, books.created, movies.budget, movies.revenue
FROM books 
INNER JOIN movies 
ON books.movie_id=movies.id 
WHERE price >= $1 
AND (movies.budget = $2 OR movies.revenue = $2) 
ORDER BY books.created ASC 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

This throws me a `missing FROM-clause entry for table \"movies\"` error. I debugged it and the problematic part is the `AND (movies.budget = $2 OR movies.revenue = $2)`, without it the query runs fine .

There are a lot of questions about this error but I couldn't find one where the problem/solution applied to my case. Does anybody have a clue where the problem is here?

Comment: Are you sure about those $ chars in your query. Looks wrong in my eyes.

Comment: Is the query part of the proc?

Comment: This: `for table \"movies\"` would seem to be the culprit. Looks like something is trying to escape a value. What is the value being substituted into `$2`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver a valid VARCHAR value, if it's calling fields from `books` ex. `books.title` or just `title` it is working properly.

Comment: `budget` and `revenue` look like numeric fields to me. What if you run the query in `psql` with the `movies.budget`  and `movies.revenue` manually set? Also per @Serg comment where is this being run? Finally what is the actual value for `$2`? Add answers as update to the question.

Comment: Are there literal backslashes in the error message?